# Jmeter Key Extraction value in the response

Tags: json, api, jmeter, response, jsonpath

I want to extract the key value generated from response, is there's a way to simulate using JSON Path extractor?

Sample Response:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "1637042070532561": {
            "symbol": "BAUa",
            "side": "buy",
            "quantity": "1",
            "limitPrice": "2145",
            "instrumentId": 4,
            "created": "1637042070533",
            "orderStatus": "rejected",
            "type": "limit",
            "executions": {
            },
            "decimals": 2,
            "commission": "0",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "averagePrice": "0",
            "id": "1637042070532561",
            "filledStatus": "unfilled",
            "filledPercent": "0.00",
            "filledQty": "0"
        }
    },
    "action": "set-orders",
    "type": "orders",
    "status": "OK",
    "timestamp": "2021-11-16T05:54:30.536Z"
}
```

Expected Result: `1637042070532561`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor), it provides [`keys` function](https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html#keys) allowing querying JSON attribute names, in your case the query would be something like:

```
keys(data)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri the syntax you provided works fine, what if I want to extract the created keys in the response? May I know what is the correct syntax? Thank you again.